# python pandas: split string into date and time in datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a field in my dataframe df, labeled date, but after testing it a lot, I figured out that it is a string and not a date format.

```
Transaction_id | Date
ABC              4/1/2016 9:13:58 PM
CDE              10/3/2015 10:12:25 AM
EFG              12/12/2017 3:02:45 PM
```

I need to split the Date column up into Date & time and I want them to be in datetime format. I don't know how to do this with regex, since the lengths are different.

Output:

```
Transaction_id | Date                    | Date2       | Time            
ABC              4/1/2016 9:13:58 PM       04/01/2016    21:13:58
CDE              10/3/2015 10:12:25 AM     10/03/2016    10:12:25
EFG              12/12/2017 3:02:45 PM     12/12/2017    15:02:45
```

Comment: FYI, your dates are of not consistent format. First row is 12-hr format, others are 24-hr.

Comment: sorry - typo; should have been 3 instead of 15; fixed, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that I placed a `errors='coerce'` to handle non-sensical date data.

```
date2 = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, errors='coerce')

df.assign(Date2=date2.dt.date, Time=date2.dt.time)

  Transaction_id                   Date       Date2      Time
0            ABC    4/1/2016 9:13:58 PM  2016-04-01  21:13:58
1            CDE  10/3/2015 10:12:25 AM  2015-10-03  10:12:25
2            EFG  12/12/2017 3:02:45 PM  2017-12-12  15:02:45
```

Comment: Date parsing issue, with `9:13:58 PM` should be `17:13:58`?

Comment: Thanks... will fix

Comment: Data is inconsistent with 12hr and 24hr timestamps.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!

Comment: @jeangelj not yet.  This is broken.  the `%p` directive isn't being respected.  I'm looking for a fix.

Comment: @jeangelj Fixed